# Combine Dictionary with value and sum remaining fields

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I have a list of dict :

```
mylist = [
{
   "cost": 2.0, 
   "random": 5, 
   "type": "A"
}, 
{
   "cost": 3.0, 
   "random": 3, 
   "type": "B"
}, 
{
   "cost": 0.0,
   "random": 0, 
   "type": "C"
}, 
{
   "cost": 2.0, 
   "random": 18, 
   "type": "D"
}
]
```

I want to combine the dict with "type":A and "type":B and add the values in the remaining fields such that the expected output is :

```
mylist = [
{
   "cost": 5.0, 
   "random": 8, 
   "type": "A"
}, 
{
   "cost": 0.0,
   "random": 0, 
   "type": "C"
}, 
{
   "cost": 2.0, 
   "random": 18, 
   "type": "D"
}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution you are looking for. This program would iterate through all items of list, find all dicts where type is either A or B, would sum them and produce the output as shown

```py
a = [
    {
        "cost": 2.0,
        "random": 5,
        "type": "A"
    },
    {
        "cost": 3.0,
        "random": 3,
        "type": "B"
    },
    {
        "cost": 0.0,
        "random": 0,
        "type": "C"
    },
    {
        "cost": 2.0,
        "random": 18,
        "type": "D"
    }
]
final_dict = []
cost = []
random = []
for i in a:

    if i["type"] == "B" or i["type"] == "A":
        cost.append(i['cost'])
        random.append(i["random"])
    else:
        final_dict.append(i)

final_dict += [{"cost": sum(cost), "random": sum(random), "type": "A"}]
print(final_dict)
```

Output

`[{'cost': 0.0, 'random': 0, 'type': 'C'}, {'cost': 2.0, 'random': 18, 'type': 'D'}, {'cost': 5.0, 'random': 8, 'type': 'A'}]`

Comment: @Austin Working as you expected??

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the required values and add them, and then insert it to original one, while iterating with lists remember to use slice to copy.

```
mylist = [
{
   "cost": 2.0, 
   "random": 5, 
   "type": "A"
}, 
{
   "cost": 3.0, 
   "random": 3, 
   "type": "B"
}, 
{
   "cost": 0.0,
   "random": 0, 
   "type": "C"
}, 
{
   "cost": 2.0, 
   "random": 18, 
   "type": "D"
}
]

def combine(*types):
   temp = []
   for l in mylist[:]:
      if l.get('type') in types:
         temp.append(l)
         mylist.remove(l)

   x = {}
   for t in temp:
      for k,v in t.items():
         if x.get(k):
            x[k] += v
         else:
            x[k] = v
   x['type'] = types[0]
   mylist.insert(0,x)

combine('A','B')
print(mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is small function that will do just that:

```
def sum_by_type(l, type1, type2):
    dict1 = None
    dict2 = None
    for rec in l: # iterate over list and find needed types
        if type1 == rec["type"]:
            dict1 = rec
        elif type2 == rec["type"]:
            dict2 = rec

    if not (dict1 or dict2): # check if both types were found
        raise Exception("Not type found")

    for k, v in dict1.items():
        if k == "type":
            continue
        dict1[k] += dict2[k]

    l.remove(dict2)
```

Now all you need to do is to pass your list and two types that you want to sum:

```
mylist = [
    {"cost": 2.0, "random": 5, "type": "A"},
    {"cost": 3.0, "random": 3, "type": "B"},
    {"cost": 0.0, "random": 0, "type": "C"},
    {"cost": 2.0, "random": 18, "type": "D"},
]

print(mylist)
sum_by_type(mylist, "A", "B")
print(mylist)
```

**Output:**

```
[
    {"cost": 2.0, "random": 5, "type": "A"},
    {"cost": 3.0, "random": 3, "type": "B"},
    {"cost": 0.0, "random": 0, "type": "C"},
    {"cost": 2.0, "random": 18, "type": "D"},
] # before


[
    {"cost": 5.0, "random": 8, "type": "A"},
    {"cost": 0.0, "random": 0, "type": "C"},
    {"cost": 2.0, "random": 18, "type": "D"},
] # after
```